# Can numpy sort a list of dictionary objects or are pandas dataframe operations my only option for this?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am using a public API to get data. I need to sort the response object (list of dictionary items) by a specific column. I am able to do this in a pandas dataframe but wanted the speed boost if possible with numpy. Is this possible?

Comment: A `pandas` dataframe is based on a [`(structured) np.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html) and adds convenience functions. There is no benefit to using `numpy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort almost any kind of data with builtin `sorted`, just define a custom key that returns what ever you want to sort by:

```
l = [
    {"a": 2, "b": 4, "s": "1st"},
    {"a": 1, "b": 5, "s": "2nd"},
    {"a": 3, "b": 3, "s": "3rd"},
    {"a": 5, "b": 1, "s": "4th"},
    {"a": 4, "b": 2, "s": "5th"}]

l_sorted = list(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x["a"]))
print(*l_sorted, sep="\n")
print()
l_sorted = list(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x["b"]))
print(*l_sorted, sep="\n")
print()
l_sorted = list(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x["s"]))
print(*l_sorted, sep="\n")
```

Edit: If you are dealing with large datasets, using pandas DataFrame is a good idea since it has lot of common functionalities already implemented, like sorting: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html