# How do I sort on a specific value in a dictionary in python flask within a template

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, flask

I am new to Python and Flask and I am trying to loop through this dictionary below as a test pre-getting data from a DB and sort it out on a specific field/column other than just printing the list out in the order I have created it.

i.e. This will simply print out the

```
    {% for data in db_get_show_application_overview %}
        <TD> {{ data.sao_application }} </TD>
        <TD> {{ data.sao_primary_app_name }} </TD>
        <TD> {{ data.sao_physical_server_name }} </TD>
    {% endfor %}
```

But I would like to be able to order this say via the sao_physical_server_name field or the sao_primary_app_name as an example and not via the order it is created in as it would have been in a dB for example. I have looked to find something similar but I cannot seem to find anything. If this has been already answered then sorry.

Is this possible?

```
db_get_show_application_overview = [
{
    'sao_application': {'name': 'appname1'},
    'sao_line_num': '1',
    'sao_primary_app_name': 'A Application',
    'sao_physical_server_name': 'server1'
},
{
    'sao_application': {'name': 'appname2'},
    'sao_line_num': '2',
    'sao_primary_app_name': 'C Application',
    'sao_physical_server_name': 'server1'
},
{
    'sao_application': {'name': 'appname3'},
    'sao_line_num': '3',
    'sao_primary_app_name': 'B Application',
    'sao_physical_server_name': 'server1'
}
```

]

Thank you,

Paul

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can numpy sort a list of dictionary objects or are pandas dataframe operations my only option for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074102/can-numpy-sort-a-list-of-dictionary-objects-or-are-pandas-dataframe-operations-m)

Answer (score 1):

Try to sort the list in backend before passing it to the template.

Instead of passing it as it is:

```
return render_tamplate('your_template.html', db_get_show_application_overview=db_get_show_application_overview)
```

pass the sorted one:

```
return render_tamplate('your_template.html', db_get_show_application_overview=sorted(db_get_show_application_overview, key=your_key_function))
```

You can sort the list using key function. This is the [sorted documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#sorted) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3.9/howto/sorting.html) is good tutorial for how to use the key function.

For example you can sort them based on `sao_line_num`:

```
sorted(db_get_show_application_overview, key=lambda item: item['sao_line_num'])
```

Comment: This is a good idea. I will look at doing that prior to sending through. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:-

```
db_get_show_application_overview = [
{
    'sao_application': {'name': 'appname1'},
    'sao_line_num': '1',
    'sao_primary_app_name': 'A Application',
    'sao_physical_server_name': 'server1'
},
{
    'sao_application': {'name': 'appname2'},
    'sao_line_num': '2',
    'sao_primary_app_name': 'C Application',
    'sao_physical_server_name': 'server1'
},
{
    'sao_application': {'name': 'appname3'},
    'sao_line_num': '3',
    'sao_primary_app_name': 'B Application',
    'sao_physical_server_name': 'server0'
}]

print(sorted(db_get_show_application_overview, key = lambda x: x['sao_physical_server_name']))
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try both of these options.